# Чтобы собрать Релиз приложения для Iphone в VISUAL STUDIO обязательно нужен MAC?

Tags: visual-studio, mac

Только что прочитал, что "да" нужен. Но не могу с этим ни как смериться. Может можно как-то малыми деньгами обойтись. К примеру облачным решением воспользоваться? сейчас читаю Комменты на других сайтах, говорят дорого все-равно облачное решение. Проще, говорят, купить бу Mac.
Посоветуйте облачное решение или подходящую модель MACa.(дешевое естественно и рабочие пусть и медленное)
=(

Comment: Вариант Б/У не рассматривали?

Comment: только что просматривал бу, но хочется все-таки решение, где не нужно будет покапать еще одно устройство. так подумал ну возьму за 10 или меньше какое-нибудь старье плохо работающие(по мне кот в мешке). Еще и места занимать будет дома. Сейчас буду искать облачные решения, может есть с оплатой за день.

Comment: нашёл почасовую аренду $1 в час на английском сервис. по запросу mac os cloud. Но вопрос открыт, так как хочется услышать опыт других в данной ситуации.

Comment: А хакинтош в виртуалку поставить? Сработает?

Comment: @AlexSazonov, хакинтош - это нарушение лицензии Apple.

Comment: А кто узнает? )) Ну а если серьёзно, раз под яблоко разрабатываешь, наверное имеет смысл обзавестись каким-нибудь лэптопом. Эйр 2012-2013 можно найти за 25к. Или же искать какие-то другие обходные пути.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вроде даже если установить Mac OS в виртуалку, то все равно нужно будет покупать у Apple лицензию разработчика, иначе приложение даже в дебаге не запустится. Поправьте меня кто в теме.